# Error "The execution role you provide must allow AWS EventBridge Scheduler to assume the role."

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-event-bridge

I'm creating a role to reboot automatically an EC2 instance. But I'm getting this error "The execution role you provide must allow AWS EventBridge Scheduler to assume the role."

[image]

In the role, I've added those permissions

[image]

I know it's mostly too much but still not enough cause I'm getting the error... Any idea ?

Comment: Can you please add how did you create the execution role and how are you trying to attached it to the EventBridge Scheduler?

Comment: I just created manually a role in IAM and a eventbride rule manually too. Not sure to understand your question

Answer (score 31):

You need to add the below trust policy to your execution role which will allow EventBridge Scheduler to assume the role.

Open IAM Console → In the navigation pane of the console, choose Roles and then choose your role → Select Trust Relationship tab → Click on Edit trust Policy and add the below policy.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "scheduler.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Also `Service` in the trust policy should be `scheduler.amazonaws.com` not `events.amazonaws.com`.

Answer (score 2):

Since the error message indicates EventBridge Scheduler is unable to assume the role, you are probably missing the IAM piece that allows the "sts:AssumeRole" action. [This doc for IAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/troubleshoot_roles.html#troubleshoot_roles_cant-assume-role) describes where you need to add these permissions.

```
"Effect": "Allow",
"Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
"Resource": "arn:aws:iam::account_id_number:role/role-name-you-want-to-assume"
```