# The execution role you provide must allow AWS EventBridge Scheduler to assume the role

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I trying to configure autostop/start rds with this link: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/schedule-amazon-rds-stop-and-start-using-aws-lambda/
but when i configure schedule in amazon eventbridge i have error:

> The execution role you provide must allow AWS EventBridge Scheduler to
> assume the role.

i create a role with policy

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "lambda:InvokeFunction"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:lambda:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:function:stoprds:*",
                "arn:aws:lambda:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:function:stoprds"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and add in trust relationships

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "events.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

but it's doesn't work

Comment: Please use the policy and the steps mentioned here in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76093093/12326605

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/scheduler/latest/UserGuide/setting-up.html#setting-up-execution-role), `Service` for EventBridge Scheduler should be `scheduler.amazonaws.com`, not `events.amazonaws.com`.

Comment: yes previous step i put: 
{
 "Version": "2012-10-17",
 "Statement": [
  {
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Principal": {
    "Service": "scheduler.amazonaws.com"
   },
   "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
  }
 ]
} but i still have same error

Comment: @Jennifer Then you have some other mistakes in your architecture. Sadly you haven't provide any information about what are you doing. The error you get is because of what I wrote in the answer.

Comment: I trying to configure autostop/start rds with lambda functions. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/schedule-amazon-rds-stop-and-start-using-aws-lambda/ i stopped when i create rule to stop rds in system manager