# How to create a EventBridge scheduler with Node.js

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, scheduler, aws-event-bridge

My setup is pretty simple. I am using sst to create a graphql lambda endpoint. Sst also creates an EventBridge Bus and an EventBridge Rules. So whenever I send the proper event to the bus this trigger a second lambda function that sends an email containing the report requested by the user. Everything works as expected till this point.

```js
    import { EventBus } from "@serverless-stack/node/event-bus";
    import aws from "aws-sdk";

      await new aws.EventBridge()
        .putEvents({
          Entries: [
            {
              EventBusName: EventBus["AffinityBus"]?.eventBusName,
              DetailType: "reportInput",
              Detail: JSON.stringify({
                endDate: params.endDate,
                startDate: params.startDate,
                filters: params?.filters,
                campaignId: params?.campaignId,
              }),
              Source: "sendCampaignReportByEmail",
            },
          ],
        })
        .promise();
```

But my requirements demand that the user should be able to schedule this report email. This is the main reason I am using EventBridge in the first place. He its why I am trying to do

```js
    import {
      CreateScheduleCommand,
      FlexibleTimeWindowMode,
      SchedulerClient,
    } from "@aws-sdk/client-scheduler";

    const ebc = new SchedulerClient({ region: awsConstants.AWS_REGION });
    const command = new CreateScheduleCommand({
        Name: "newScheduler",
        GroupName: "affinity",
        ScheduleExpression: `repeat(${calculateRepetition(params)} minute)`,
        FlexibleTimeWindow: { Mode: FlexibleTimeWindowMode.OFF },
        Target: {
          Arn: "arn:aws:scheduler:::aws-sdk:eventbridge:putEvents",
          RoleArn: "arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:role/name",
          Input: JSON.stringify({
            endDate: params.endDate,
            startDate: params.startDate,
            filters: params?.filters,
            campaignId: params?.campaignId,
          }),
        },
        StartDate: new Date(params.startDate),
        EndDate: new Date(params.endDate),
      });
    
    await ebc.send(command)
```

This is the error I am facing, but that is very weird, because there is no Entries field on the awsv3 typescript types. What should I do??

```bash
2023-05-03T11:37:06.436Z    c6dc2287-9444-4a58-8acd-775b70742f2d    INFO    ValidationException: The execution role you provide must allow AWS EventBridge Scheduler to assume the role.
    at de_ValidationExceptionRes (/var/task/resolvers/query.js:49572:25)
    at de_CreateScheduleCommandError (/var/task/resolvers/query.js:48998:23)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async /var/task/resolvers/query.js:47664:24
    at async /var/task/resolvers/query.js:52804:22
    at async /var/task/resolvers/query.js:51678:42
    at async /var/task/resolvers/query.js:50762:26
    at async scheduleCampaignReport (/var/task/resolvers/query.js:76875:22)
    at async handler149 (/var/task/resolvers/query.js:76915:23)
    at async Runtime.main [as handler] (/var/task/resolvers/query.js:78241:16) {
  '$fault': 'client',
  '$metadata': {
    httpStatusCode: 400,
    requestId: '0c71a1bb-ccff-4a77-a8ed-3a6d9e8ccbb5',
    extendedRequestId: undefined,
    cfId: undefined,
    attempts: 1,
    totalRetryDelay: 0
  }
}
```

I can replicate the same error with the cli. By running the following command

```
aws scheduler create-schedule --name cevent-bridge-schedule --schedule-expression 'rate(5 minutes)' --target '{"Arn": "arn:aws:scheduler:::aws-sdk:eventbridge:putEvents", "RoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::xxxx:role/myrole", "Input": "{\"Entries\": [{\"EventBusName\":\"dev-affinity-appsync-AffinityBus\", \"DetailType\":\"reportInput\" , \"Detail\":\"{}\" , \"Source\": \"sendCampaignReportByEmail\" }]}" }' --flexible-time-window '{ "Mode": "OFF"}' --region us-east-1  --debug
```

Comment: As the error "ValidationException: The execution role you provide must allow AWS EventBridge Scheduler to assume the role." indicates you need to add the trust policy to your execution role which will allow EventBridge Scheduler to assume the role. Follow the steps as mentioned here in the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76093093/12326605